# is there a way to count the number of files in a folder via google sheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm doing a log for files at work and I need a formula or a way to "get" the amount of files in a folder (that i've on pc not in gdrive).
es: in **A1** I want the **number of files** in the *XXXXX *folder on the pc...I hope I was clear.
thank you

*number file on folder* ->  i've ...    A1  .pdf file in my folder

Comment: Excel or Googlesheets? There is a difference. Which one are you using?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)